# Selenium clicking alternative

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to automate the use of a web service.

Whenever I try to click on elements within the web page using Selenium the result is strange, it seems as if the web page is able to detect whenever I click using Selenium.

Whenever I click using my cursor the web page functions normally even if I set a break point mid application and start clicking it works fine.

Is there any alternative in .NET or Python that I could use to automate clicks in a similar fashion or perhaps avoid detection of these clicks on the service?

```
        action.MoveToElement(element, 158, 208).Click().Build().Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            action.MoveToElement(element, 258, 158).Click().Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            action.MoveToElement(element, 228, 158).Click().Build().Perform();

            //var screenshot = new Screenshot();
            //screenshot.CaptureScreen(Convert.ToString(i + 1) + ".png");

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

The service is an image service, whenever I click done to confirm that image has been processed, it will keep the image visible rather than making it disappear but when I interrupt and click it myself, it will disappear. The reason this is bad is the visible image will overlay the new image, the selenium clicked image will stay visible and manual clicks will not.

I am using the latest version of ChromeDriver and Selenium however I have tried Mozilla & IE with and other versions of selenium and web drivers with no avail.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you feel _web page is able to detect whenever I click using Selenium_ ? Which _WebDriver_ variant (GeckoDriver/ChromeDriver/IEDriverServer) are you using along with the version info of the binaries you are using?

Comment: @DebanjanB The service is an image captcha service, whenever I click done to confirm that image has been processed, it will keep the image visible rather than making it disappear but when I interrupt and click it myself, it will disappear. The reason this is bad is the visible image will overlay the new challenge, the selenium clicked will stay visible and manual clicks will not. I am using the latest version of ChromeDriver and Selenium however I have tried Mozilla & IE with and other versions of seleniums with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of putting CAPTCHA on a site is exactly to tell machines and people apart, so

> seems as if the web page is able to detect whenever I click using Selenium

is working as designed. For *simple* captcha you can call some free [ocr.space online OCR](https://ocr.space/ocrapi) service. This will work just fine as long is an image with a text.  You can also try [Google Cloud Vision OCR](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) which works equally well, but it is a bit more complicated to set up.